# Duplicate rows if certain columns has values and copy to next sheet with duplicated rows

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this problem where if there is a value in a column, the row should be duplicated and copied to the next sheet. I will show a scenario to understand better.

This is sheet1

[image: Sheet1]

As you can see from the table above, there is a certain item name that doesn't have the three quantity columns. Some only have good quantity, some have both good and bad, and some have the three quantity. Now I want to copy this data to the other sheet with some modifications.

This should be the result in the next sheet:

[image: SHEET2]

As you can see, the data are duplicated based on the quantity columns if there is data or not. The status column is based on the quantity columns in sheet1. `Status 0` is `GOOD QTY`, `Status 1` is `BAD QTY` and `Status 2` is `VERY BAD QTY`.
This is my current code:

```
    Set countsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set uploadsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    countsheet.Activate
    countsheet.Range("B11", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    uploadsheet.Activate
    uploadsheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I know this code only copies data from `sheet1` to `sheet2`. How to modify this code and achieve the result above?

Comment: Are you locked into using VBA?  Power Query can make this an easily repeatable task.

Comment: @JodyHighroller I'm not familiar with power query. If this is possible using excel, can you show me an answer?

Answer (score 0):

- Select your data range > Data tab in the ribbon > From Table/Range
  [image]
- Select the Item Code and Item Name columns > right-click > Unpivot Other Columns
  [image]
- Select the Attribute column > right-click > Replace Values.  You can type in two dummy values: Value To Find = abc, Replace With = xyz

[image]
[image]

This code will appear in the formula bar:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","abc","xyz",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"})
```

Replace it with this:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each [Attribute], each if Text.Upper([Attribute]) = "GOOD" then 0 else if Text.Upper([Attribute]) = "BAD" then 1 else 2,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Attribute"})
```

- I used the Text.Upper function because Power Query is case sensitive.
- Now all you need to do is rename the columns and select Close & Load > Close & Load To > Table
- This is a beneficial technique because as you add, edit, or remove data from your source table you can just refresh and the PQ table will update accordingly.